# HTML/CSS Two Columns/One Row Second Row Wrapping If Browser Width Is Too Small

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

I am creating a web page that shows a series of rows. Each row has two columns. The first column consists of an image and the second column has two rows (it might have more later but for now I only have two).

Here is a quick sketch of what I am after:

[image: div sketch]

Here is my HTML markup:

```
<div id="extensions" class="extensions">
    <div class="extensions row">
        <div class="extensions row icon">icon</div>
        <div class="extensions row details">
            <div class="extensions row name">Name: Some Name</div>
            <div class="extensions row desc" style="">Description: Some description blah blah blah.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see the root div (extensions) contains all the rows. To create the first column (icon) I put a div directly below the root div. Next, I create another div which is the parent for the rows (name and desc).

Here is my CSS:

```
.extensions {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 95%;
}
.extensions .row  {
    margin: 5px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.extensions .row .icon {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
.extensions .row .details {
    display: inline-block;
}
 .extensions .row .details .name {
    border: 1px solid orange;
}     
.extensions .row .details .desc {
    border: 1px solid purple;
}
```

(Note the borders are for debugging only.)

Everything looks fine when my browser is wide enough as shown below:

[image: unwrapped div]

However, if I make the browser width smaller eventually the second column gets wrapped below the image column:

[image: wrapped div]

I have tried various ways to prevent this from happening to no avail.

Can anyone tell me how to stop the second column from wrapping? Do I need to create another div to put both the image column and the details column all inside one div?

Thank you.

Comment: [FIDDLE CHECK](http://jsfiddle.net/GopsAB/pGK8r/) Do you want this?? Specify width in percentage.

Comment: Yeah that's what I kinda already have until the browser wraps the div when it gets to small.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[FIDDLE0](http://jsfiddle.net/GopsAB/pGK8r/)

[FIDDLE1](http://jsfiddle.net/GopsAB/pGK8r/1/)
                Specify width in percentage. It will solve your problem.

```
.extensions 
{
 font-family: sans-serif;
 font-size: 95%;
 width: 100%;
}
.extensions .row  
{
 margin: 5px;
 border: 1px solid red;
 width: 100%;
}
.extensions .row .icon 
{
 display: inline-block;
 border: 1px solid green;
 width: 10%;
}
.extensions .row .details 
{
 display: inline-block;
 width: 50%;
}
.extensions .row .details .name 
{
  border: 1px solid orange;
  width: 70%;
}      
.extensions .row .details .desc {
 border: 1px solid purple;
 width:70%
 }
```

Comment: That seemed to work thanks! Another quick question... how to I align the image so that it's always in the middle? I tried vertical-align: center but that seemed to put the image at the bottom.

Comment: Quick question, without providing the width can you explain why it wraps? In other words, does specifying the width force the HTML render to continuously calculate the width as the page is shrinking and keep it on one line?

Comment: I currently have text there ("image") but eventually I am going to replace the text with a <img> element and I want the image to always appear vertically centered with respect to the row height.

Comment: Without specifying width, it ll take default width. It's content-length. SO if it exceeds screen width, it ll fall into next line. If you specify width, It ll restrict content into that width [it ll increase height]

Comment: Ah okay, I understand. One other quick question.. what if I don't want it to change the height either? Perhaps something like providing a scroll-bar if the width gets too small instead of wrapping?

Comment: Use overflow property.